# Why picture is not shown in Sinatra app when I add additional level of addressing?

Tags: html, ruby, sinatra

My Sinatra app has typical file hierarchy:
root contains:

*file "hc.rb" 
file "endpoints.yml"
dir "views" 
dir "public"*

"view" contains .erb files

public dir contains:

*file "style.css" 
dir "images"*

in dir images I have favicon and 404 pictures.

here is part of the code:

not_found.erb

```
<center><img src="images/404.png" alt="404 Not Found"></center>
```

hc.rb

```
not_found do
  erb :not_found
end
```

layout.erb

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico"/>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
 </header>
 <section>
    <%= yield %>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

When I type localhost:[port]/smthnonexisting

I get 404 image on the screen

But when I type additional level

localhost:[port]/smthnonexisting/andsmthmore

I do not see the image and I see only 404 Not Found and broken image ico.

What can be the reason?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that you're using a path relative to the current folder. When you visit `http://localhost/smthnonexisting` your browser is looking for the `styles.css` file at `/styles.css`. When you visit `http://localhost/smthnonexisting/andsmthmore`, your browser is looking for the `styles.css` file at `/smthnonexisting/styles.css`.

This is solved by keeping your references relative to the 'root' folder, by a `/` before `styles.css`, like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
```

You should also do the same with the favicon, and any other included files:

```
<link rel="icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" />
```